# Unknown error using EDIDev

Tags: vb.net, edi

I'm trying to generate an 837P EDI file using EDIDev. I was able to generate 4 other 837P files but on the 5th one I tried I get the following error when I try to Save the file:

> Edidev.FrameworkEDI.ediException: '[DESCRIPTION:Terminator characters
>   present in data.  Release indicator not specified][CODE:12378]'

I thought it was simple enough, I just needed to find where the terminator character is present in the data, remove it and I should be good to go. I'm extremely inexperienced with EDIDev so I hope I provide the right information to troubleshoot. I thought to go look at the terminators. The program is written using VB.NET. The SegmentTerminator is set to be "~" & vbCrLf. The element terminator is set to be the "*" and the composite terminator is set to be the ":". I searched for each of these characters in the source data and they were not to be seen. The source file is a .xlsx file. Keep in mind, I was able to translate 4 files before I failed on this fifth one. I don't really know what else I can provide for troubleshooting purposes. I would post some code but 1) its really big and 2) I wouldn't know what piece to cut out and simplify down because I don't know where to look for the source of the error. Can someone give me any suggestions as far as what to do to figure out what is causing so much grief in my code?

Answer (score 1):

After many an hour of pouring over this, I came to realize that how I was storing some values in my database that is being used to generate the file was including a ":" in it and that was what was causing the problem. However, the issue still exists that I pose to anyone that would like to answer: what is a better way of troubleshooting this? How would I go about pinpointing the error in the future? The error message didn't give any indication to the exact point in the code where the error was being introduced.